# Downloading SpaceNet Dataset: Permission Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dataset, cloud

I am trying to download [SpaceNet](https://registry.opendata.aws/spacenet/) Dataset by following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/the-downlinq/getting-started-with-spacenet-data-827fd2ec9f53). Upon entering this command

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket spacenet-dataset \
--key AOI_1_Rio/processedData/processedBuildingLabels.tar.gz \
--request-payer requester processedBuildingLabels.tar.gz
```

I get this output:
Permission Denied: 'processedBuildingLabels.tar.gz'

I am using Windows 10 cmd and I already have an active AWS account and I entered the access and secret keys using "aws configure" command. Any ideas why I cannot download it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you don't have permission to create the file `processedBuildingLabels.tar.gz` locally. Trying running `touch processedBuildingLabels.tar.gz` and see if you get the same error. If so, trying running the command as root, e.g.

```
sudo aws s3api get-object --bucket spacenet-dataset \
--key AOI_1_Rio/processedData/processedBuildingLabels.tar.gz \
--request-payer requester processedBuildingLabels.tar.gz
```

Comment: Is "touch" a unix/linux-based command? Because I am on windows and cannot use it. I tried looking for an alternative, all I found was **"copy /b processedBuildingLabels.tar.gz +,,"** and the output is "the system cannot find the file specified" (because I could not download it in the first place)

Comment: Try `echo.> processedBuildingLabels.tar.gz`. There is no `sudo` on windows either, so if you don't have permissions you'll need to edit the folder permissions or figure out how to use `runas`

Comment: When I execute "echo.> processedBuildingLabels.tar.gz" I get "access denied" (even though I have admin permission?). So I guess I will look into the possible solutions you gave me :) thanks for your help!